# win32com, function PageSetup.Pages.Count works incorrectly

Tags: python, excel

I need to merge all .xlsx files into one and perform end-to-end numbering. Merging is performed using the function:

```
def collect_to_one():
"""Function copies to one file"""
sgmts = segmentation(start_page)
for book in range(len(sgmts)):
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Add()
    for file in range(len(sgmts[book])):
        print(sgmts[book][file])
        w = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sgmts[book][file]))
        w.Sheets(1).Copy(After=wb.Worksheets(file + 1))
        wb.ActiveSheet.Name = sgmts[book][file]
        w.Save()
    wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '_'.join(('Сводный', sgmts[book][-1]))))
```

The next function performs end-to-end numbering of each sheet in the summary file:

```
def enum(start_page):
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Сводный_09-04-01 +.xlsx"))
for i in range(2, len(files) + 2):
    ws_list = wb.Worksheets(i)
    ws_list.Application.PrintCommunication = False
    ws_list.DisplayPageBreaks = True
    print(ws_list.PageSetup.Pages.Count)
    ws_list.PageSetup.FirstPageNumber = start_page
    start_page += ws_list.PageSetup.Pages.Count
    ws_list.Application.PrintCommunication = True
wb.SaveAs(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Сводный_09-04-01 +.xlsx"))
```

Unfortunately, ws_list.PageSetup.Pages.Count works incorrectly. For example, I have 6 files, and  print(ws_list.PageSetup.Pages.Count) leads to this result:
0 (actually the file contains 4 pages)

0 (actually the file contains 4 pages)

0 (actually the file contains 5 pages)

0 (actually the file contains 35 pages)

0 (actually the file contains 7 pages)

2 (actually the file contains 2 pages)

But if I open the summary file and swap 2 sheets, and then I will return the original location of sheets, the function enumerate correctly. Of course, I can do the same by adding 2 strings of code:

```
wb.Sheets(2).Move(Before=wb.Sheets(4))
wb.Sheets(2).Move(Before=wb.Sheets(4))
```

But anyway, it's a little bit strange. How to fix it?